# Got comment everywhere without the needed rep. Bug?

Tags: support, comments

Title says it all.

This morning (locally speaking) I got the "comment everywhere" privilege. It says it's given when user reach 50 reputation...but I have 49 O_o

Comment: Can you comment anywhere at the moment? Just guessing it might have been an upvote that got reversed within the grace period.

Comment: Lol. You are wright, I did not even think about this case. In this moment I cannot comment, right. My fault, it's not a bug. Or...well, maybe it is a bug the missing notification about losing a privilege?

Comment: You are never notified of losing privileges.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *briefly* gained enough points to earn you the privilege. Perhaps someone upvoted one of your posts then undid the upvote.

You are notified of a gained privilege just once. If you then lose the points again, you are not notified of the lost privilege, nor are you notified again if you regain the points. This is by design; someone could easily troll you by voting and undoing the vote in quick succession, over and over again, otherwise. And you *did* gain that privilege, so not giving you the notification the first time around would be wrong too.